# Error: Class 'Haml' not found... trying to use Haml (Kohaml) with Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, haml, sass, fatal-error

Can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Downloaded Kohaml from http://github.com/transphorm/kohaml

Dropped it into modules/kohaml

```
 # My Bootstrap reference
 'kohaml'     => MODPATH.'kohaml',        // kohaml
```

Keep getting this error... (snapshot of the error and my modules folder)

http://wellcommentedcode.com/stack_kohaml_question/

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong would be highly appreciated... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. Had to update the filenames like you said. Thanks again for reporting the bug. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a lot of the class files had names that started with a capital letter... went and lowercase them and that fixed the previous error... but all my standard views are now broken with this error.

http://wellcommentedcode.com/stack_kohaml_question/cache.jpg

Any clues?